# check if user inserted value higher then 0 with vanilla js

Tags: javascript

I am creating a custom js validator from scratch, without the use of any libraries.

I want to validate a numeric `input` by checking if the user-inserted content in the `input` tag is great than `0`:

```
<label>Price
    <input type="text" id="price" name="price">
</label>
```

Attempt:

```
function price() 
{
    if (#price.value>0)
        console.log('0.');
    else
        console.log('Incorrect');
}
```

Comment: You're going to need to use vanilla `document.getElementById('price')` to access your input element.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Check if user inputed value higher then 0 with pure vanilla js

Comment: `#price` isn't valid syntax nor is the recommended way to access DOM elements. Use `document.getElemenyById("price")`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function price() 
   {
    var price = document.getElementById("#price"); // get the element
    if (isNaN(price.value) || price.value <= 0) // if the value is not a number or is less than 0
        console.log('Incorect');
    else // otherwise
        console.log('Correct');
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this not work:

`if(price.value.match(/^[0-9]+$/) && +(price.value) > 0){`

im not quite sure what the hash symbol is being used for so i removed it in my example. Unless you are trying to find the ID in which you would have to look for the element like so:

`var price = document.querySelector("#price");`

Comment: This does not work. Outputs error 'cannot read property of null'

Answer (score -1):

**How about some thing like that**

```
  var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
    if (parseInt(price) > 0 && !isNaN(price)))
      {
        // then do something 
      }
    else 
      {
        // else do something
      }
```

Comment: @ down voter if you are down voting any question explain and put some constructive comments about the problem.